# how to edit wireshark pcap to change the order of packets

Tags: network-programming, wireshark, packet-capture, tcpdump, wireshark-dissector

i have a pcap file captured using wireshark. suppose the pcap has 6 packets numbered from 1 to 6 as shown below. now i want to edit this pcap file so that i get the packets in some different order. For eg, if original pcap packets are

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

i want a new pcap after editing, where now packets are in the order (say for example) as :

```
2,3,1,4,5,6
```

similarly i can have some other order for eg, 2,4,5,6,1,3 or any other order.

Can anyone let me know how can i do that ? (may be using wireshark or any other method).
any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use combination of [editcap](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) and [mergecap](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html)

To solve your problem:

```
editcap -r in.pcap tmp1 2-3
editcap -r in.pcap tmp2 1
editcap -r in.pcap tmp3 4-6
mergecap -w out.pcap -a tmp1 tmp2 tmp3
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried this thing, but its not working. from above it seems that "2-3 1-1 4-6" is the order in which we want the packets in the resulting pcap. But this gives all the packets mentioned in the same order. With the above command, in.pcap (having only 6 packets) and out.pcap were same. Is this working for you ?

Comment: Was shure it worked for me. But it doesn't. You can still use combinatinon of editcap and mergecap. I'll update the answer.